# Pricing credit risky bonds

Tags: fixed-income, bond

How do we price credit risky bonds?

If I discount the cash flows using LIBOR/zero rates, it won't take the credit riskiness into account. So should I use a rate based on the issuer's credit spread? Or is there a separate way to price in credit riskiness (maybe using default probabilities)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you do indeed add a credit spread $s$ to the risk-free spreads to price the bond.    That is, if the coupons are $c_i$ at times $t_i$ and the notional is $Y$ then you price it as

$$
R\!B(t) =Y \exp{\left( -\int_t^T s(x)+r(x) dx  \right) } +\sum_{i \ni t_i>t}^{N_c} c_i \exp{\left( -\int_t^{t_i} s(x)+r(x) dx  \right) }
$$

Normally you have too little information to incorporate a term structure for $s$, so you just make it some constant $s_0$.  Once in a while you have enough information from other bonds or credit default swaps to determine a term structure.